# How to open/load a saved Meld patch file?

Tags: patch, meld

I'm using [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) which is great in `diff view` almost the same as [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) way in file comparison.

Now let's see the `Format as Patch...` feature of Meld - please see the below snapshot. My question is after saved, how can we load/open the file?

[image]

A sample saved patch file is as below.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by open/load the file? Where would you like to open/load it?

Comment: @ckruczek I would love to open/load it by Meld, of course.

Comment: Well I tried meld a bit. And as it seems, you can't load the patch to meld again. Actually its kind of senseless to do this. So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ckruczek I just feel curious and have the guessing that the `Format as Patch...` feature is created to serve some needs - my need is to load the saved one

Comment: @ckruczek I just need to way to save the compare result and load to review later on.

Comment: Yes ofcourse it serves some needs. It is needed ir you send somebody a patch and one wants to applie the patch via git.

Comment: So Git can open that?

Comment: Yes. Git is able to apply patches as fron meld generated.

Comment: @ckruczek I'm not familiar with Git - may you guide a bit more on which Git client to do so. Thanks a ton!

Comment: There is no specific git client which is able of handling patches. Its a git core feature. You may search for git apply patch on google. And you find tons of information how go handle this